# How to make function wait for another?

Tags: javascript

i have a function, that call another function:

```
function_name(1)
function function_name (i) {
  multiply(i)
  console.log(i); // 1
}
function multiply (i) {
  i = i*2
}
```

When it's executing, `console.log(i)` return "1".
I need console.log(i) to return "2".
how can i make it wait till `multiply()` will be executed?

Comment: have `multiply` take `i` as a reference or return `i` and store it in `i`. Right now `i` never changes from 1.

Comment: Waiting is not the issue, variable scoping is.

Comment: JavaScript uses **pass-by-value**, not pass-by-reference. The variable `i` inside `function_name` points to a different memory location than variable `i` in `multiply`.

Comment: As @rgbchris has hinted, the issue isn't that the line `console.log(i)` is executed before `multiply` has finished - in fact that line absolutely *will not* execute until `multiply(i)` has exited.  The problem is you are doing absolutely nothing that will change the value of `i` within the scope of the `function_name` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to wait, those methods are synchronous so the `console.log()` is executing only after the `multiply()` is executed. The problem is you are only updating the local scoped variable `i` in the multiply so the locally scoped variable `i` in `function_name` will not be modified by the actions in `multiply`

You can return the result from multiply and use that value in the calling function like

```
function_name(1);

function function_name(i) {
    i = multiply(i);
    console.log(i); // 1
}

function multiply(i) {
    return i * 2;
}
```

Comment: I think you miss the semicolon after multiply(i)

Answer (score 3):

Right now `i` is never changed.

If you do the below, it should work:

```
function_name(1);
function function_name (i) {
  i = multiply(i);
  console.log(i); // 2
}
function multiply (i) {
  return i = i*2;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `// 2`?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, true. fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```js
function_name(1)

function function_name (i) {
  i = multiply(i); //Makes 'i' equal to the value returned
  console.log(i); // 2
}

function multiply (i) {
  return i = i * 2; // returns the value
}
```